# Is there a java monitoring/alerts framework for a cluster?

Tags: java, monitoring, snmp, metrics

I have a cluster of servers.  Common tasks I manualy code are:

1. collect various stats (failures, success, times) with [metrics](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics) library.
2. aggregate those combine cross cluster.
3. depending on conditions check out the aggregated stats **cross cluster** and based on that send alerts.  (instead of having each server send an alert, increase global metrics which are polled then to [graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/)).
4. if a specific node send an alert its first accumulated and base on alerts from other nodes (again cross cluster scenario) then I woudl decide which alert to send (so if i have 100 servers not each of them send a separate alert but single one).

I looked into a few frameworks but none of them that I see achieve this: [metrics](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics), [javamelody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/), [netflix servo](https://github.com/Netflix/servo), [netflix zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul)

but none of them support for example my **cross cluster** scenario where i want to aggregate stats over time and only if certain conditions apply send an alert (as a method to avoid duplicating alerts cross servers).  Do I need to build my own framework for that? or is there already something existing?

(and in case my use case sounded specific so that I should just code it, i have many more such similar use cases which makes me think why isn't there such a framework, before i start coding something i don't want to find i just duplicated some other framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using a combination of either Graphite or OpenTSDB with Riemann?  You can aggregate your information in Graphite (with or without statsd) or dump everything into OpenTSDB and use Riemann for event processing?  Riemann's config is in Clojure but I believe you can use client libraries in multiple languages (unless you want to do the event processing yourself using Esper/Siddhi).  Another option could be to look at Rocksteady (whcih uses Graphite/Esper).  Graphite is a Python/Django application (there are multiple forks of statsd - not just the one in NodeJS & besides, you can simply use metrics in place of that).  OpenTSDB is Java on HBase (if you're looking to store time series information).  For event processing, you could also choose to look into Storm (and use Esper/Siddhi as a bolt in Storm).

Comment: are zabbix capablities for https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/aggregate and https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions comparable to those of riemann?